# Regular expression for text with multiple character delimiter

Tags: asp.net, regex, vb.net

I have a text file like this:

```
::content1 ...
...
::content2 ...
...
::content3 ...
...
```

So the text (multiple line) is delimited by "::" and I want to find the matches in between. Perhaps the best way is to replace "::" with one character and then use the split method in VB.Net. But I wonder if this can be done also with a regular expression, like this:

```
Dim myRegex as RegEx = new Regex("...")         
m = myRegex.Match(content)
Do While m.Success
    ...
    m = m.NextMatch()           
Loop
```

It seemed easy but I can't find the right regular expression pattern.

**Edit:**
Someone asked what I had already tried. I have tried negative lookahead, but it does not work. (I use the [\S\s] instead of ".", because I understand the period does not match a new line character. Maybe this is my poor understanding of regular expressions.)

```
    Dim myRegex as RegEx = new Regex("::(?![\S\s]+::)[\S\s]+")
```

Comment: I was assuming the VB.Net split method supports only one character, but maybe this is not correct. But this was not my question.

Comment: Please add at least the expressions you've tried. And if the delimiter is always in the beginning of the row it should be easy. Or if it is not please add an actual sample of the data

Comment: I have provided an example. And yes, the delimiter is always in the beginnning of a row (new line).

Comment: `.` does not match a newline by default, but you may redefine the behavior to match any char by using the `RegexOptions.Singleline` option. Note that you may really split with a string. However, if you need to split with `::` that are at the start of a line, then you need a regex like `(?m)^::`. Could you add these details and also state what the expected output should look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note your `::(?![\S\s]+::)[\S\s]+` pattern matches `::` that are not followed with any 1+ chars (`[\s\S]+`) followed with `::`, and then matches any 1+ chars. That makes the pattern find the last `::` and what is after it.

Note that in this case, you might really do without a regex *if* the `::` always delimit the contents. Here is a way to do it:

```
Dim result As String() = str.Split(New String() {"::"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
```

If you want to split with `::` that are at the beginning of lines, you might want to use a regex like

```
Dim result As List(Of String) = Regex.Split(str, "^::", RegexOptions.Multiline).Where(
        Function(m) String.Equals(m.Trim(), String.Empty) = False).ToList()
```

where `RegexOptions.Multiline` will make `^` match the start of a line, not the start of a string.

Comment: You are right about that my pattern only found the last `::` and after that. I haven't tried your regular expression, but I take your advice better not to use them in this case.

Comment: What I was driving at is that regex is great when you want to get parts of text in some specific context that can be described with regex. In case you just have to divide text with a literal string, you do not have to use regex, it is not appropriate to use at this moment.

Answer (score 0):

No need to use regular expression. Split the text by `::`.

```
content.Split("::")
```

Comment: @esims To use more than a Char you need `Split(YourString, "::")`